# Why my question was moved to another stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My question was about Bitlocker](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/273047/feeding-bitlocker-with-a-startup-key-from-a-network-service) and therefore ultimately was about disk encryption. But my question was moved to superuser.com for reason of "Not suitable for this site".

Isn't disk encryption part of infosec?

Now, I am not saying that superuser.com is not suitable. Just want to understand...

A related question is there a site / group policy as there is on other social media (LinkedIn for instance)?

Comment: I provided an explanation when I migrated it.

Comment: "Not suitable for this site" does not count as an explanation to me. It is just a justification.

Comment: You've reduced my comment to the rediculous (or you missed my comment *under* your question).

Comment: I missed it. But I still do not see anything other than what I cite above.

Comment: You moved this yet another site. Again there is no policy not even a purpose / charter available for a site under stackexchange. In fact the information security meta site is not even listed on the All sites page

Comment: Have you read the FAQ? https://security.stackexchange.com/help It explains the process for how to handle a closed question, including asking here on Meta. So, yes, there is a purpose and charter.

Comment: Ah, I miss the links at the bottom of the home page for the site. Indeed there is a lot of information there, particularly the Tour. Can I suggest to put that at the top left side of the page; the "charter" is important and should be promoted.

Comment: Were you not presented with a tour and a pointer to the FAQ when you joined? The help center is also linked in the close banner.

Answer (score 2):

Your question wasn't at all about disk encryption. Your question was about what Windows is doing outside of disk encryption. That's a Windows-internals question, not a security question.

Comment: So talking about how to securely provide encryption keys is not infosec? If so, then TPM and how Windows handles it is also out of scope, right? IIUC, then this group is about cypher, protocols and other things of that nature.

Comment: That's an error in logic. You've made a false leap.

Comment: "Is it possible to have some software started from the system drive, i.e. before Bitlocker starts Windows from the Operating System drive" - that's not about securely providing keys.

Comment: "Is the network operates when the Bitlocker is doing its thing?" -- that's not about securely providing keys

Comment: Let me provide a model for you to think about: Firewalls are typically in the security domain. Firewall appliances get their power from a plug in the wall. Questions about how to provide security using a firewall are on topic. Questions about how to power a firewall appliance are not. Just because the goal that prompted the question may have been about security doesn't mean that the specific question you asked was.

Comment: But if binding the firewall to a specific power plug is what securely provides the configuration to the firewall, would that counts as a security question? In the end, what I want to do with the network is similar to RedHat's NBDE.

Comment: Then questions about power go to an electrical engineering site, not a security site. The end goal doesn't guide the topic; the content of the question does.

Comment: Again, what you asked was about how Windows works, not about BitLocker, disk encryption, encryption, or security. You want to know that so that you can devise something that relates to security, but the questions themselves are about Windows internals.

Comment: You are correct. I agree. Probably the stack overflow would be a better place. I am not sure Sure User is specific enough; I have always regarded it for admin, not developers. Without a clear charter we must based judgment on site title, which is not  enough.

Comment: BTW, before asking my question I did search for answer. I found a question related to mounting a USB drive for feeding Bitlocker the security key on the infosec site. This is how I heard about the site in the first place and prompted to ask my question there.